# ProgressDialog is not closed

Tags: android, progressdialog

I managed to show a ProgressDialog, but I can't close it after my long running process. 
Does anyone know what is wrong here.

All methods are directly under my onCreate() of my Activity.

This is my snippet of the code.

```
private final Handler updateHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
        dismissWaitDialog();

    };


    public void showWaitDialog(String sTitle, String sMessage){
        waitDialog=new ProgressDialog(this); 
        waitDialog.show(this, sTitle, sMessage);
    }

    public void dismissWaitDialog(){
        waitDialog.dismiss();
    }


public void longrunner(){
    showWaitDialog("Please wait","Please wait");

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            do something long
            updateHandler .sendMessage(mymessageinit);
        }
    }.start();  
}
```

Comment: Use AsyncTask instead.. By the way what is exception you are getting

Comment: No Error. Just not closing the dialog. All runs further.

Comment: Is it getting close when back button is pressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a static [`show()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#show%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method that returns an instance of `ProgressDialog` that you throw away. The dialog you dismiss is not the same that is showing. To fix, change:

```
waitDialog=new ProgressDialog(this); 
waitDialog.show(this, sTitle, sMessage);
```

to

```
waitDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, sTitle, sMessage);
```

As mentioned by others, an `AsyncTask` is really the canonical way to perform operations like this instead of working with `Thread`s directly.

Comment: Yupee ! Thanks a lot . Working now !

Answer (score 2):

use asyncTask.

add your code in `doinbackground();`

show dialog in `preexecute();`

dismiss progress dialog after complete your `doinbackground();`